# phpunit runs very slow when the assertion fails

Tags: php, phpunit

I am studying phpunit and I have noticed when my assert fails the summary takes a lot of time to show the result (but not when the test is correct).

For example if I run this test, it takes half second to show the the green bar:

```
<?php
class SomeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testSomething() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
?>
```

But the same test with a fail assert takes 12 seconds to show the red bar:

```
<?php
class SomeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testSomething() {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
?>
```

Now this time is not acceptable if I need to run tests continuously during the developing.
What can I do to speed up the process?

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem since I upgraded to php 5.4 / phpunit 3.7.24 on a windows 7 box.
I debugged and found out that PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState#phpunitFiles() is the culprit, it spends around 7 seconds finding PHPUnit and PEAR files to filter out from the stack trace.

I filed an issue : https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1007

For the moment as a workaround I'll try to cache the files array on disk

```
public static function phpunitFiles()
{
    if (self::$phpunitFiles === NULL) {
        $phpunitFilesCache = '/path/to/my/file/phpunitFiles'; // CHANGED
        if (is_file($phpunitFilesCache)) { // CHANGED
            self::$phpunitFiles = unserialize(file_get_contents($phpunitFilesCache)); // CHANGED
            return self::$phpunitFiles; // CHANGED
        } // CHANGED
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('File_Iterator');
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHP_CodeCoverage');
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHP_Invoker');
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHP_Timer');
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHP_Token');
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase', 2);
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase', 2);
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator', 2);
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase', 2);
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase', 2);
        self::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList('Text_Template');

        file_put_contents($phpunitFilesCache, serialize(self::$phpunitFiles)); // CHANGED
    }

    return self::$phpunitFiles;
}
```

Comment: +1 - especially for trying to fix the problem (by creating a ticket for it).

Comment: I'm still having this problem, even though it seems like they patched it in 3.7 (https://github.com/TomCan/phpunit/commit/b6746d1ea3454670d507a9bfa683fc377a90ec30)